I want to checksum from a sector to another sector on a hard drive, is this possible?
As the question states I would like to do a checksum on the sectors before the boot partition. Here is a example of the partition table:



Area Name
Size
From (sector #)
To (Sector #)




SPL
512kB
64
1077


U-Boot
2MB
2048
6143


BOOT _
256MB
6144
530431


rootfs
-
530432
-



This is from: fdisk /dev/mmcblk0



Device
Boot
Start
End
Sectors
Size
Id
Type




/dev/mmcblk0p1

6144
530431
524288
256M
83
Linux


/dev/mmcblk0p2

530432
122142719
121612288
58G
83
Linux



What I want to do is run a command to do a checksum of the SPL partition, and also the U-Boot partition. I want to checksum from sector 64-1077 and from sector 2048-6143. Any ideas?

Well I think I should use dd,
I'm not sure if my math is correct or if this is the right answer,
mkdir /var/tmp/spl
mkdir /var/tmp/u-boot
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/var/tmp/spl/spi bs=512 skip=63 count=1014
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/var/tmp/u-boot/u-boot bs=512 skip=2047 count=4096
cksum /var/tmp/spl/spl
cksum /var/tmp/u-boot/u-boot
If this is correct, does skip=63 mean it starts at sector 64? I did 1077-64+1 for my math on first example, it might be wrong. So I think this puts 2 files in memory and then I can cksum those two. I haven't tried this, I'll wait for a couple comments on this. For added background I plan to do this in initramfs before cryptroot-unlock over ssh.

does skip=63 mean it starts at sector 64 No, assuming by sector 64 you mean LBA 64, since LBA starts from 0, so there are 64 (LBA 0-63) blocks to skip. Also you can omit of=path/to/file and pipe the stdout of dd to cksum or whatever.

Thanks much I think I figured it out what you mean. dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=512 skip=64 count=1014 | cksum > /var/tmp/spl

I wonder why the count for SPL is not 1024 (512 * 1024 / 512).
